# SQL Select where a column contains one value but not another in another row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table on the picture below.
I'm trying to select all rows with DestinationSystemID "11" where other rows with the same SupplierPartyID does not also have DestinationSystemID "16".

For example in the table below the following rows should be selected because they have rows with DestinationSystem 11, but not 16:

- 7300009017706
- 7300009043088
- 7330509000502

The following should not be selected because it has both DestinationSystemID 11 and 16:

- 7318270000006

I hope you understand what I'm trying to ask here.

[image: Table]

I have tried searching for solutions but can not query the question correctly to find a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` works quite nicely for this:

```
SELECT {explicit t.columns}
  FROM dbo.YourTableName AS t
  WHERE t.DestinationSystemID = 11
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT 1 FROM dbo.YourTableName AS t2
        WHERE t2.SupplierPartyID = t.SupplierPartyID
          AND t2.DestinationSystemID = 16
    );
```

Some will suggest `NOT IN` but I firmly believe this is an inferior solution and can lead newer users astray.

[Here is why you should avoid `NOT IN`](https://dbfiddle.uk/0MHxxBwA) in general, even if *in this specific case* the column is not `NULL`able *today*. Readers will take that "working" solution and apply it other scenarios or discover a lot of broken queries when the column becomes `NOT NULL` later. More elaborate background [in this blog post](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) mentioned in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

`NOT IN` will also work with this as another option:

```
SELECT * FROM test a
WHERE DestinationSystemID = 11 
AND SupplierPartyID NOT IN (SELECT SupplierPartyID
                            FROM   test b
                            WHERE  a.SupplierPartyID = a.SupplierPartyID
                            AND b.DestinationSystemID = 16)
```

**Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/qKgxuosn).**

**Note:** Consider using `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN` if the target column accepts `NULL` values (See *Accepted* Answer above).

Comment: Good to know that detail in the future, thanks.

Comment: No, [`NOT IN` is a bad recommendation](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join). Read the comments, too. It may work in this case if we make an assumption about the OP's table _today_, but other people will come across this solution and use it incorrectly, even with the disclaimer.